# sharepoint online - Powerapp integration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I want to integrate a workflow done with Powerapp into a sharpoint online website, but when I follow the instructions displayed here -> https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-powerapp-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-online-9338b2d2-67ac-4b81-8e67-97da27e5e9ab
There is no drop-down list for Powerapp anywhere on the page when I look at my list. Do I make a mistake by following the instruction? Or is this an sharepoint  online limitation?

Comment: Are you in the new or old-classic view in sharepoint? I think the option is only available in the new view for sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section "Activating PowerApps in a SharePoint list" in the document link you shared. You need to enable this for your list in the Advanced Settings for the list app if this is not enabled by your tenant administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I think its `List Settings`, `Advanced Settings`, `New Experience`
[image]